# Getting Error: CS1061 in unity when adding a member function

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to modify a card game project where there is a function to determine whether the deck created by a player is a basic deck.

I am considering a modification, adding a similar function to determine whether the deck is a special deck.

As a beginner in C#, my idea is quite simple: I see a class with a member function A(), so under the code of A() I just copy and paste it to make a similar function B(). And I only use B() together with A() so that there should be no namespace problems: If the A() works well then my B() should also work because they are from the same class the same file.

However, the result is that in another .cs file the origin A() works well but my B() shows error CS1061:

'DeckModel' does not contain a definition for 'IsSpecialDeck' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'DeckModel' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How could it happen? I have tried things like rebuilding/recompiling.

src\Cynthia.Card\src\Cynthia.Card.Common\GwentGame\GwentDeck.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Alsein.Extensions.Extensions;

namespace Cynthia.Card
{
    public static class GwentDeck
    {
        public static DeckModel CreateBasicDeck(int defaultDeckIndex)
        {
            //some other codes......
        }
        public static bool IsBasicDeck(this DeckModel deck)//A(),the original one
        {
            var decks = deck.Deck.Select(x => GwentMap.CardMap[x]);
            var deckFaction = GwentMap.CardMap[deck.Leader].Faction;

            if (decks.Any(x => x.Faction != Faction.Neutral && x.Faction != deckFaction))
                return false;

            if (decks.Count() < 25 || decks.Count() > 40)
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Gold).Count() > 4 ||
                decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Silver).Count() > 6 ||
                decks.Any(x => x.Group == Group.Leader))
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Gold).Distinct().Count() != decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Gold).Count() ||
                decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Silver).Distinct().Count() != decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Silver).Count())
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Copper).GroupBy(x => x.CardId).Select(x => x.Count()).Any(x => x > 3))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        public static bool IsSpecialDeck(this DeckModel deck)//B(), my work
        {
            var decks = deck.Deck.Select(x => GwentMap.CardMap[x]);
            var deckFaction = GwentMap.CardMap[deck.Leader].Faction;


            if (decks.Any(x => x.Faction != Faction.Neutral && x.Faction != deckFaction))
                return false;

            if (decks.Count() < 25 || decks.Count() > 40)
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Gold).Count() > 8 ||
                decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Silver).Count() > 12 ||
                decks.Any(x => x.Group == Group.Leader))
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Gold).GroupBy(x => x.CardId).Select(x => x.Count()).Any(x => x > 3) ||
               decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Silver).GroupBy(x => x.CardId).Select(x => x.Count()).Any(x => x > 3))
                return false;

            if (decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Copper).Distinct().Count() != decks.Where(x => x.Group == Group.Copper).Count())
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

the client code

(src\Cynthia.Card.Unity\src\Cynthia.Unity.Card\Assets\Script\MathMenu\MatchInfo.cs):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Cynthia.Card.Client;
using Cynthia.Card;
using UnityEngine;
using Alsein.Extensions;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;
using Assets.Script.Localization;
using Alsein.Extensions.LifetimeAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Alsein.Extensions.IO;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;



public class MatchInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    //other attributes and methods here.....

    public async void MatchButtonClick()/////pressing the match button
    {
        try
        {
            //already in qneue
            if (IsDoingMatch)
            {
              
                await _client.StopMatch();
                return;
            }
            //if the deck is special
            //error CS1061: 'DeckModel' does not contain a definition for 'IsSpecialDeck' accepting a first argument of type 'DeckModel' could be found
            if(_client.User.Decks.Single(x => x.Id == CurrentDeckId).IsSpecialDeck())
            MatchButtonText.text="special"+MatchButtonText.text;
            //if the deck is not special and not basic,stop matching
            else if (!_client.User.Decks.Single(x => x.Id == CurrentDeckId).IsBasicDeck())
            {
                await _UIService.YNMessageBox("PopupWindow_IncompleteDeckTitle", "PopupWindow_IncompleteDeckDesc", "PopupWindow_OkButton", isOnlyYes: true);
                return;
            }
            //otherwise start matching
            _ = _client.MatchOfPassword(CurrentDeckId, MatchPassword.text);

            //some other codes....

        }
        catch
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("LoginScene");
            _client.ClientState = ClientState.Standby;
        }
    }
    //other methods...
}
```

the DeckModel class

(src\Cynthia.Card\src\Cynthia.Card.Common\Models\DeckModel.cs):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Cynthia.Card
{
    public class DeckModel : ModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public List<string> Deck { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public string Leader { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Format your code. It looks like IsSpecialDeck i inside  IsBasicDeck

Comment: Formatted now. I use colored parentheses extension in my vscode so I think no problem here

Comment: An extension method (like your `IsSpecialDeck`) needs a `using Cynthia.Card;` (the namespace its class is in). Why not make it a plain instance method?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment so I'll ask in an answer. What type is `_client.User.Decks.Single(x => x.Id == CurrentDeckId)`. I don't see an `Id` field or property in the DeckModel class. Is it possibly in ModelBase? Perhaps the type returned by Single or the type of Decks is a parent class rather than the DeckModel class. It is hard to try it myself as I dont have all the code.